# Is is possible to have path argument (domainname.com/somepath) for grpc client using python

Tags: python, grpc

I'm trying to connect to my `grpc` server, which is currently hosted in Azure. Because of some issues, I had to set up ingress controller to listen for `grpc http2` under a specific path:
`domainname.com/cameragrpc`. I know **it works** because I tested it with `postman` client.

I believe the problem is that the Python library doesn't like when I declare a `grpc` url with path:

```
url = "domainname.com/cameragrpc"
async with grpc.aio.secure_channel(url, channelCredentials) as channel:
```

Currently, it gives me this error:

```
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "DNS resolution failed for domainname.com/cameragrpc: UNAVAILABLE: WSA Error"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for domainname.com/cameragrpc: UNAVAILABLE: WSA Error {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-08-10T09:25:41.0504345+00:00"}"
```

For some reason the code that runs it, treats the `domainname.com/cameragrpc` as a full domain name, at least that's what it looks like, as when I change it to `domainname.com` then it resolves the domain, but fails on `http2` support.

Any ideas if there is any way to tell the python grpc to accept path argument or maybe there is another library which supports such a behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

According to the gRPC / http2 protocol (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md), the http2 path header is: "/" Service-Name "/" {method name}

Note that the http2 path header is per-RPC thing, i.e. different RPCs on the same channel can have different path headers, depending on what the RPC service/method is.

The example of "domainname.com/cameragrpc" is indeed not supported with gRPC. But you might still be able to route based on path header with something like this:

- create the channel to "domainname.com"
- somehow configure path header based routing by matching grpc's path header - e.g. something like "/cameragrpc/MyRPCMethod" or "/cameragrpc/*"