How to call gRPC in nestJS?
@Client({
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      package: 'cpo',
      protoPath: protoPaths,
      url: `${process.env.GRPC_URL}`,
      loader: {
        longs: String,
        includeDirs: includeDirs,
        defaults: true,
      },
    },
  })
  client: ClientGrpc;

This works if the GRPC_URL is something like this:
something.com:443
But in my case, the endpoint is:
something.com:443/grpc
It has the /grpc and I can't call it because it returns:
'Failed to parse DNS address dns:something.com:443/grpc'

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

The grpc is your package name that should be included in the proto files. but you have configured it as 'cpo'. This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76874543/is-is-possible-to-have-path-argument-domainname-com-somepath-for-grpc-client-u
